# Can we use 'react-router' in native applications as well for routing purpose?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

We have a React project where we used `react-router` for routing purpose. Now, We are going to develop native app where we will have to implement routing once again.Here my doubt is,

Can I use the same package(`react-router`) for native app as well?.

Why I am asking is I have gone through an article(https://medium.com/@spencer_carli/exploring-navigators-in-react-native-869b6ab47e0f) where multiple navigators have been listed, among them them `react-router` is not listed.

Comment: Have you looked at `react-router-native` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-router can only be used in React web App and not in react-native app. Instead you can use the react-native-router-flux for the react-native app which takes less transition time and all the routes can be listed in the single Javascript file similar to react-router.

Comment: Got exactly what I want. Thank you